# Mapped array of tuples to object doesn't produce correct values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types, typescript-types

A friend of mine was trying to write a type which did a conversion similar to the runtime behavior of `Object.fromEntries`; that is convert a type for an array of two-element tuples (say `[["a", number], ["b", string]]`) to a type for an object with those types as key-value pairs (in this case, `{a: number; b: string}`).

His first attempt to do this was the below, which didn't work:

```
type ObjectKey = string | number;

type EntryKey<T> = T extends [infer K, unknown]
  ? K extends ObjectKey
    ? K
    : never
  : never;

type EntryValue<T> = T extends [ObjectKey, infer V] ? V : never;

type ObjFromEntriesBad<Entries extends [ObjectKey, unknown][]> = {
  [Index in keyof Entries as EntryKey<Entries[Index]>]: EntryValue<
    Entries[Index]
  >;
};

// Incorrect: is `{a: string | number; b: string | number;}
type Test1 = ObjFromEntriesBad<[["a", number], ["b", string]]>
```

I wrote a simplified version which I thought should work, but it failed with compiler errors:

```
// Error: Type '0' cannot be used to index type 'Entries[Index]'
type ObjFromEntriesBad2<Entries extends [ObjectKey, unknown][]> = {
  [Index in keyof Entries as Entries[Index][0]]: Entries[Index][1]
};
```

I finally came up with a solution that seemed to work:

```
type ObjFromEntriesGood<Entries extends [ObjectKey, unknown][]> = {
  [Tup in Entries[number] as Tup[0]]: Tup[1]
};
```

My questions are then: why didn't the first solution work? Why does the second solution cause compiler errors? And finally, in the working solution we iterate of `Entries[number]`, but is there a way to create a correct type while still iterating over `keyof Entries` in the mapped type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original versions don't work because currently (as of TS4.4 anyway) there is no support for [mapping array and tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) while also [remapping the keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#405886](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40586) for a suggestion to, among other things, change that.) As soon as you try, the mapped object gets all the keys of the array, including things like `"push"` and `"pop"` and `number`:

```
type Foo<T> = { [K in keyof T as Extract<K, string | number>]: T[K] }

type Okay = Foo<{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }> // same
type StillOkay = Foo<{ 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3 }> // same
type Oops = Foo<[1, 2, 3]>
/* type Oops = {
    [x: number]: 1 | 2 | 3;
    0: 1;
    1: 2;
    2: 3;
    length: 3;
    toString: () => string;
    toLocaleString: () => string;
    pop: () => 1 | 2 | 3 | undefined;
    push: (...items: (1 | 2 | 3)[]) => number;
    concat: {
        (...items: ConcatArray<1 | 2 | 3>[]): (1 | ... 1 more ... | 3)[];
        (...items: (1 | ... 2 more ... | ConcatArray<...>)[]): (1 | ... 1 more ... | 3)[];
    };
    ... 23 more ...;
    includes: (searchElement: 1 | ... 1 more ... | 3, fromIndex?: number | undefined) => boolean;
} */
```

So in `ObjFromEntriesBad`:

```
type ObjFromEntriesBad<E extends [ObjectKey, unknown][]> = {
  [I in keyof E as EntryKey<E[I]>]: EntryValue<E[I]>;
};
```

You'll get `number` as one of the `I in keyof E`, and `EntryKey<E[I]>` is the full [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the keys, and `EntryValue<E[I]>` a full union of the values, and you lose the correlation you care about.

And in `ObjFromEntriesBad2`:

```
type ObjFromEntriesBad2<E extends [ObjectKey, unknown][]> = {
  [I in keyof E as E[I][0]]: E[I][1]
};
```

this problem persists.  There's no `0` or `1` indices in `E[I]` when `I` is something like `"push"`, so the error is correct.   A lot of times the compiler couldn't verify that such indices were safe even if they were, so you would probably end up falling back to the `EntryKey` and `EntryValue` solution which uses  [conditional type inference via `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to sidestep such issues.

---

For your third question, you can't iterate directly over `keyof E`, that's the whole problem.  You could do something similar, though, like use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to explicitly filter out all the arraylike properties:

```
type ObjFromEntries3<E extends [ObjectKey, unknown][]> = {
  [I in Exclude<keyof E, keyof any[]> as EntryKey<E[I]>]: EntryValue<E[I]>;
};
```

And verify that it actually works:

```
type Test3 = ObjFromEntries3<[["a", number], ["b", string]]>
/* type Test3 = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFQHxQLxQN5QNoDSUAlgHZQDWEIcAZlMlAIYDOUAogB7ABOTAxsEQEANFBa8yAcygAfKKQCuAWwBGEHqgC6ALgaEtUAL4BYAFDnQkKAHkKTEJlgJEuJnoCMY1XoBMY-j0AZmN0AHow8SZlCEtwaABlYGIAGxS7Byd4JFwABk8xDz8xX2DQqAiomLjrGzgwNixsxDwvKH8oIK1UczCAKigraDqGp2xzKEn8Tj0lNQ1dKA85dpWggG4JqfylzbMppb89g9LO46mUiFIpYAALYPPJ4Dgknmk9AAoASkx0CTfro9BnAADJwfhMS6vd5Qb6-cSSQFbSZgeqfH4YdDLeS+NYrRSkAAmEFoZAghKBYEULHusIAdAziMAIMoWJ9sat5EEvngtBj0HN1Dwgfw4KQIcA9ON9gcph8GXSmSy2VAAMJiiUAQR4fBAiA5uK5qF5X3ZKwVSygyjgPGgFq5PK0QIO8sZzNZZvkFtx1ttUHtao1TGA2t1iAVqEdpthHIty19doZa0dQKMQO9IQT-oZQLI-BSimJKo+LAgTB4-Fu7EuMVIkstXqT8ZtibpazEtB4cGUAEkiRBOAB+WYqIX4-uk0jk-lQVQIS5MUh7IxQPphcwbsxDKAALSyLlaJTEXR6Fi38VsqgAVhBBARqE5-tIVoKNHsatB2HWeCB73q0E4jADsyRJsHgZC0BoUCiFABIUKQcAAO6kFoWyDtBUDAVchJsDY163sAf5odBWyzBAABuGikQoFFvpu25frwIAAGqQooEAoOgWBAdw2FgXhN53tQYgQVBzGGOhzFQGRlHCvRF4CTAXbKIxbwQCwABCTCEog7CYbxoH4AJBF-mIcEIchWi8lxOBbHgPYkOQVA0PQemsBw36-tQun2d0iyqSxbEcewvmoMu75mJUfaijqBF6MQbAAAbYO4CIAjI8ivsKs56E+1wvqOb6mOe1jIOpwDLFginKapxDqVpOl4HgABETDNWIWVaGILWqO1aXSFo3Sbr0kTsDqNp6MgF4AOS5NNUAQqQCHALO0DUuSwKOcSnCDDNtXqfZ-acFo00fpeV5Kd2+2adpvi6fpIE4UZ+FCSAZmkPBSEodZYx2Q5ZCUNQdAcMwbAhT2Vm5INejg1ZHioWYabDSVwzXpdKnfnVLBBPdWGGXgxmve9n2WT9WDSpM9mORwnD5oWHHOcD7BiIz9CLiAP3uQFf4+RD2gw55rEFsFoXhfJpXlSEVVozVmPqTjTWtX1nXdc1vViHlUiDae-S7RLEhS7ZMqTKlWVAj4-VIojq7rme5hAA)

Comment: Had no idea that remapping the keys would change the set of keys being mapped - feels a bit like there's too much magic happening under the hood when somewhat orthogonal features have such an interaction. Anyways, thanks for the great explanation - amazing answer as always!

One additional question - you said "A lot of times the compiler couldn't verify that such indices were safe even if they were, so you would probably end up falling back to the EntryKey and EntryValue solution." Why would that be? In this case at least, the compiler "should" be able to verify it's safe, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "in this case at least"?  Nothing stops someone from writing `ObjFromEntries<[] & { oops: 123 }>` so it's still possible that there's a key whose value is not assignable to `[ObjectKey, unknown]`; you'll find that the hoops you need to jump through to make 100% sure that the property values are the types you care about (and also convince the compiler of that fact) will end up being similar to the conditional type inference solution from before.